# mysql left join results in 4 records instead of 1

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I know I am doing something silly here

Should this left join not give only one record?

My sql fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/251f7/1

Also, If a kind soul can help me put the productName in one field separated by commas

```
required output
id1 id2 productName
a1  x1  copier,headphone,cable,monitor
```

Comment: It is good that you've posted a fiddle, but you should also provide data and desired output in your post, along with your current attempt.

Comment: I have data in fiddle and required output in my question. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`left join` in your example works perfectly fine, the way it should, to concat `productName` in one string with separator you should do a `group by` and use `group_concat`:

```
select ForgeRock.id1
     , ForgeRock.id2
     , group_concat(ForgeRock.productName)
from TClock
left join ForgeRock on TClock.id1 = ForgeRock.id1 and 
                       TClock.id2 = ForgeRock.id2
where colour = 'red'
group by ForgeRock.id1
       , ForgeRock.id2
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/251f7/2)

Comment: Thanks, that works great. I always thought left join would work without "group by". Do you need the "group by" because there is AND operator?